# Having to click twice to recover part of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, history.js, scrollmonitorjs

I'm doing a script that uses pushState to change the page title and url based on the part of page the user is.

My script is at JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tnc0fouu/

Here's the script:

```
var nowDiv = 0;
    var divs = new Array();
    divs.push([
        "lipsum1", // div id
        "lipsum1", // url
        "Lipsum 1" // title
    ]);
    divs.push(["lipsum2", "lipsum2", "Lipsum 2"]);
    divs.push(["lipsum3", "lipsum3", "Lipsum 3"]);

    $(document).ready(function(){
        // chg_state();

        $.each(divs, function(index, value) {
            var el = scrollMonitor.create(document.getElementById(value[0]));
            var bked = 0;
            el.fullyEnterViewport(function(){
                if(bked == 0){
                    nowDiv = index;
                    chg_state();
                    bked = 1;
                }
            });
            el.exitViewport(function(){
                bked = 0;
            });
        });
    });

    function chg_state(){
        History.pushState({state:'new'}, divs[nowDiv][2], divs[nowDiv][1]);
        //alert("new state: " + divs[nowDiv][2]);

        History.options.debug = true;
        var State = History.getState();
        History.debug('statechange:', State.data, State.title, State.url);
    }
```

When I click on the browser's back button I want the page to scroll to the `div` of last state. However, I have to click twice in the back button to do what I want.

Is there a way to do that only with a single click on the back button?

Comment: I suggest using an object to encapsulate your "div". In other words, `divs.push({ id: "lipsum1", url: "lipsum1",, title: "Lipsum 1" }). The your `pushState` call looks a lot cleaner: `pushState({state:'new', divs[nowDiv].title, div[nowDiv].title)`. That won't help with your problem, but would likely help with readability.